# Why is Mysql returning an incomplete table when using where clause?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I was trying to apply a filter in the WHERE clause when making a query. I was sure there were data in the column but for some reason, the table Mysql retrieved was incomplete. I export the results to a csv file to see if data was there, and it was indeed, however it was not what I expected. I would like to know why Mysql retrieve the results like that and if there is something wrong with my queries.

At first, this was the query I was using to create a temp table.

```
SELECT a.n_tile, a.member_casual, COUNT(ride_length) AS cnt
FROM
 (
 SELECT NTILE(12) OVER (ORDER BY ride_length) AS n_tile, member_casual, rideable_type, ride_length
  FROM length
   )a
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

This is the table I got

| n_tile | member_casual | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 133903 |
|  |  | 338394 |
|  |  | 123895 |
|  |  | 348402 |

So when I query to filter my data, I got an empty set.

```
WITH h AS 
 (
SELECT a.n_tile, a.member_casual, COUNT(ride_length) AS cnt
FROM
(
SELECT NTILE(12) OVER (ORDER BY ride_length) AS n_tile, member_casual, rideable_type, ride_length
FROM length
   )a
GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT cnt
FROM h
WHERE h.n_tile=1 AND h.member_casual = 'member';
```

When I exported my results to a csv file to try to understand if data was actually there, and it is indeed. However, is in the following format:

n_tile,member_casual,count_rides

- 1,casual
- ,133903
- 1,member
- ,338394
- 2,casual
- ,123895
- 2,member
- ,348402

However, when I formated my data as shown below, and import it to Mysql as a table, I was able to filter my data with the WHERE clause.

n_tile,member_casual,count_rides

- 1,casual,133903
- 1,member,338394
- 2,casual,123895
- 2,member,348402

| n_tile | member_casual | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | casual | 133903 |
| 1 | member | 338394 |
| 2 | casual | 123895 |
| 2 | member | 348402 |

Now I have my table like this, the following query works as expected

```
WITH h AS 
 (
SELECT a.n_tile, a.member_casual, COUNT(ride_length) AS cnt
FROM
(
SELECT NTILE(12) OVER (ORDER BY ride_length) AS n_tile, member_casual, rideable_type, ride_length
FROM length
   )a
GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT cnt
FROM h
WHERE h.n_tile=1 AND h.member_casual = 'member';
```

However, I do not understand why Mysql is showing me incomplete tables. Is there anything wrong with my queries?

Comment: I'm guessing your member_casual values have newlines at the end which is messing up the csv.  But you don't tell us anything about the where clause you are having trouble with, or how you are exporting to csv, or what you mean by  "formated my data differently"; please give us more information so we can help you

Comment: Thank, I appreciate your feedback. I already included the query where I used the WHERE clause.

Comment: Show some sample data and expected and actual results for your sample data, that demonstrates the problem?  Are you sure you understand what ntile does?  Maybe try to state in English what you are trying to accomplish with this query?

Comment: I understand what ntiles does. My data is already in bins. I am trying to perform some calculations by bin and member_casual that is why I am trying to filter data. What I do not understand is why Mysql retrieves a table like the first one in the post even there is data for those columns.

Comment: If your data is already in bins, why use ntile, which puts it in bins?  Are you saying the first one in the post is with the where condition?  How are you getting the data you show?  Ideally use the MySQL  command line client, to prevent guis or csv confusing the issue

Comment: Your where is going to select the 12th of the original rows with null or least ride length, and return a count of the member ones of those.  This seems a very odd thing to do.